A die marked $1,1,2,2,2,4$ is rolled twice. Probability of getting a total score of $4$ if it is known that the obtained total is an even number is

An unbiased cubic die marked $1,1,2,2,2,4$ is rolled $2$ times. The probability of getting a total score of $4$ if it is known that the obtained total is an even number is...

My Attempt:
Number of ways to get a total score of $4$ is $1(2,2)$
Number of ways to get ab even number as total is $4(1,1)(2,2),(2,4),(4,4)$
So, probability is $\frac14$
Is this correct? Or do we need to consider $3$ cases for sum $4$ because $3$ different sides have the number $2$ on it? Also, do we need to consider ordered pair $(2,4),(4,2)?$

Those cases are not equally-likely. So you need to account for that somehow.

There is more than $1$ way to get a total score of $4$. You can roll the first and second $2$, or the first and third $2$, or the second and third $2$.

Not quite. Casework is a good approach, but you need to be careful since some of your cases are more likely than others. We can account for this by considering each pair of equally likely outcomes, of which there are $6 \times 6 = 36$.
First, let's compute the probability that an even sum is obtained. The only way this won't happen is if $1$ and a number that is not $1$ are rolled. Since there are $2$ sides that are labeled $1$ and $4$ sides that are not $1$, then there are $2 \times 2 \times 4 = 16$ ways the sum is not even. Therefore, there are $36 - 16 = 20$ ways for the sum to be even.
Now, let's compute the probability that the sum is $4$. As you observed, the only way this happens is if $2$ is rolled both times. Since there are $3$ faces labeled $2$, then there are $9$ ways this could happen.
The desired probability is therefore $\boxed{\frac{9}{20}}$.

Thankyou, means a lot.

Let $f(x)=(2x^1+3x^2+x^4)^2$ be the generating function for this problem. The coefficients correspond to the number of sides which display the number of pips equal to the power of $x$; i.e. $3x^2$ refers to $3$ of the faces displaying $2$ pips. The outer exponent refers to the die being rolled twice. When expanded, the coefficients of each power of $x$ are equal to the number of ways one can achieve a sum
equal to that power.
Expanding, we find that $f(x)=4x^2+12x^3+9x^4+4x^5+6x^6+x^8$. There are $6$ sums possible, and there are $9$ instances in which that sum will be $4$. There are $4+9+6+1=20$ instances in which the sum rolled is even, which we are told to take as given, so the final answer is $\frac{9}{20}$

Wonderful, thanks.

My attempt after K.Jiang's answer.
Total cases= number of ways to obtain $2,4,6$ or $8=2\times2+3\times3+3\times1\times2+1\times1=20$
So, probability$=\frac9{20}$
